# Raising and Lowering Indices of a Perturbed Metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, approximations, linearized-theory

I have seen in GR that if a metric is a perturbation of some base metric $g^{(B)}_{\mu \nu}$ such that

$g_{\mu \nu} = g^{(B)}_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu},$

then

$g^{\mu \nu} = g^{(B) \mu \nu} - h^{\mu \nu}.$

Does this mean that $g^{(B) \mu \nu}$ is the inverse metric such that $ g^{(B) \alpha \beta} g^{(B)}_{\beta \gamma} = \delta^{\alpha}_{\gamma}$ and that $h^{\mu \nu}$ is obtained by raising two indices of  $h_{\mu \nu}$ with $ g^{(B) \alpha \beta} $?  (I haven't matched the indices on the last one but hopefully get my meaning, you raise one index with the inverse of the base metric, then raise another one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here you are working in linear approximation, so all terms of highers orders in $h$ are negligible, so $h^{\mu \nu} = g^{(B) \mu \alpha} g^{(B) \nu \beta} h_{\alpha \beta}$, if you replace $g^{(B)}$ by $g$, the difference will be only in terms of order $h^2, h^3$.

Comment: Is it for similar reasons that the Christoffel symbol for the perturbed metric is given by $\Gamma_{ab}^c = \frac{1}{2} g^{(B)ab} (\partial_a h_{bd} + \partial_b h_{ad} - \partial_d h_{ab})$?

Comment: @Tom yes, for the same reason, maybe a more obvious way to see this, is to write $h_{\mu \nu} = \kappa \tilde{h}_{\mu \nu}$, where $\kappa \ll 1$, and consider it as an expansion in $\kappa$.

Comment: Also in GR, is it common to consider a perturbation which is time-dependent but uniform in space, so not depending on the spatial coordinates?

Comment: Well, this special case it conisedered sometimes, however, I don't think that it is most common situation

Comment: I am wondering why the answer of @spiridon_the_sun_rotator, that came after mine, and is technically incorrect has been accepted as correct and not mine. You do not raise and lower indices with $g^{(B)}$ in stead of with $g$. You always have to raise and lower indices with $g$ and then it turns out that to first order it is the same as doing it with $=g^{(B)}$.

Comment: @Обжоров, I mean that it is the same, when neglecting higher order terms, of course exact expression will involve the full tensor $g_{\mu \nu}$. But to required accuracy, there is no difference.

Comment: I only accepted as the answer was a bit longer and more detailed.  I was wondering if I could ask another question which is bothering me.  I am trying to prove something for a perturbation of a hypersurface in a spacetime (ie. a 3-manifold).  If one works in Cartesian coordinates, the metric for this 3-manifold takes the form of a conformal metric (ie. a function multiplying the Euclidean metric $\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: The proof would simplify if I were to assume that the perturbation is also given by a conformal metric, so when the perturbation acts on the metric in Cartesian coordinates $h_{11} = h_{22} = h_{33}$.  Would assuming this then restrict the result being proved to Cartesian coordinates only?

Comment: @Tom restricting the perturbation to the one, which will preserve the conformal structure is not property of a metric, but a perturbation itself. For example $ f(r, \theta) (dr^2 + r^2 d \theta^2)$ will in fact also be conformally equivalent to flat metric. For some special reason, you may be interested in perturbations such, that preserve the structure $f(x) d x^2$, i.e of form $h = h(x) dx^2$. However, in general case the perturbation will push the metric from confomally flat form

Comment: Also, although the spatial Schwarzchild metric has zero scalar curvature, I assume adding a perturbation which is itself conformally related to the flat metric will not necessarily mean that the perturbed metric as a whole also has zero scalar curvature?

Comment: @Tom Yes, after a rescaling $\tilde{g}_{\mu \nu} = e^{2 \omega} g_{\mu \nu}$, Ricci scalar transforms as follows : $\tilde{R} =  e^{-2 \omega} (R - 2(D - 1) \nabla^2 \omega - (D-1)(D-2) \partial_\mu \omega \partial^{\mu} \omega) $, where $D$ is a dimension of spacetime

Comment: When keeping terms up to linear order, Is it also the same if one has a function of the perturbation, so for example say you have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + r^2 h^{00}}} \frac{\partial h_{ij}}{\partial x^0}$, to first order would you lose the second term inside the square root, as the square root can be approximated with the binomial theorem?

Comment: When dealing with such perturvation, in the linear order you would have, now assuming $\omega$ or $h$ is small : $$\tilde{R} = (1 - 2 \omega) (R - 2 (D - 1) \nabla^2 \omega) = (1 - 2 \omega)R - 2  (D - 1) \nabla^2 \omega$$. Now Ricci scalar will be proportional to the Laplace of scaling factor.

Comment: @Tom, in the linear order you can drop the square root, and work with $\frac{\partial h_{i j}}{\partial x^{0}}$

Answer (score 2):

You raise and lower the indices with the original metric $g$
, but to fist order it is the same as doing it with the $g^{(B)}$ metric.

Comment: Could you please show me how second order terms will arise if we raise index by g rather than the base metric